# "Upload to app store" option is disabled after renewing APPLE DEVELOPER ACCOUNT

Tags: ios, xcode, upload

I had developed an IOS application and successfully uploaded it to the APP STORE. I have updated many of its versions in APP STORE but after renewing my APPLE DEVELOPER ACCOUNT when i am trying to update a new version on APP STORE i am getting “Upload to APP STORE” option disabled.It says distribution requires ENROLLMENT in APPLE DEVELOPER ACCOUNT. Please check the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are the steps that you have taken on: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/ ?

Comment: go to xcode preferences -> accounts, check here that your apple dev account is configured properly, is configured properly still getting error, then remove that account and add it again and then try. Also when you made build+archieve, have you checked that it is built with proper distributions certificates and provisioning profile(if not then that button surely will be disabled)

Comment: Just try to remove your account from Xcode --> Preference --> Accounts
And it again.

Comment: Thanks @DarshanMothreja. My problem is solved. i have removed my account from preference and add it again. It works for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AvnishSinghJohal  Great :)

Comment: Solved the problem for me too!! I had to remove the account and add it back again. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For me closing Xcode and re-open it made "Upload to App Store" enable...